# Background processes in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, sockets, web

Let's say I want to make an application that can receive connections from Socket (not page requests) clients on one socket, and simultaneously serve web forms on another socket, telling the user, for example, how many clients have connected using the other (Socket) interface. This is only loosely similar to what I'm trying to do, so don't worry if it seems nonsensical!

So, is it possible to have the server in an ASP.NET Web Forms application run another thread dealing with other things, while the web server serves the pages? Is there a recommended way of doing this, or does it need to be a bit of a hack?

Edit:
Don't worry, I switched to MVC 4, and am now using the App_Start method of starting the thread. As it doesn't matter if the thread is aborted, as long as it restarts, this is a suitable fix.

Thanks for all the help anyway though,
hnefatl

Comment: Do you have access to the server or is this a shared service provider?  You could always use a windows service or scheduled task for these types of things.  That is the preferred way; ASP.NET is not always reliable for background tasks, and is vulnerable to session timeouts, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm developing it myself (it's only very small, for personal use really). What do you mean Windows Service? The ensuing problem is that the server needs to be able to send data to the Socket clients that is input by the client who was served the page.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Later versions can self-host ASP.NET. Since you can also self-host WCF (or your own socket server code), this might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the async feature in .NET 4.5, mentioned [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx).  Basically, have a method with the "async" keyword defined, such as:

```
public async Task DoThis();
```

Register the async task:

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(DoThis));
```

Mark your page header as Async="true"

```
<%@ Page Title="Async" Language="C#" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" 
       Inherits="Whatever" Async="true" %>
```